# SpanLabel in Codename one with BoxLayout along the y axis does not span

Tags: codenameone

I need to show a list of labels one under another, but some labels may be on multiple lines. So I created a scrollable container with BoxLayout along the y-axis and tried to use [SpanLabels](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/components/SpanLabel.html), but it appears as a normal label. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I created a **scrollable** container with BoxLayout along the y-axis and tried to use SpanLabels, but it appears as a normal label. Am I missing something?

This was the key for not working. I called container.setScrollable(true), which made it scrollable in both x and y, so altough I used SpanLabel, it still showed on one line, since it can be scrolled horizontally. This:

```
    this.container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    this.container.setScrollableY(true);
    this.container.setScrollableX(false);
```

Fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Form f = new Form("Span", BoxLayout.y()); 

f.add(new SpanLabel("Short"));
f.add(new SpanLabel("Not so short"));
f.add(new SpanLabel("Not so long as to line break"));
f.add(new SpanLabel("This should totally line break because it's getting to that length where it should have an effect"));
f.add(new SpanLabel("Short"));
f.add(new SpanLabel("Not so short"));
f.add(new SpanLabel("Not so long as to line break"));
f.add(new SpanLabel("This should totally line break because it's getting to that length where it should have an effect"));

f.show();
```

[image]